# How to prove the formula for the residue of $f$ at a pole of order $m$?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Let $f$ holomorphic on $z_0$. I saw this awesome formula on a book : the residual of $f$ on $z_0$ is given by $$\text{Res}_{z_0}(f)=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\frac{\mathrm d^m}{\mathrm dz^{m-1}}(z-z_0)^mf(z)$$
How can I prove it? ($m$ is the order of pole that $f$ is assumed to have at $z_0$).

Comment: Did this awesome book also say what $m$ is?

Comment: Sorry, $m$ is the order of the singularity.

Comment: You forgot the exponent $m$ in $(z-z_0)^m f(z)$, and that formula is valid only if $z_0$ is a pole of order $m$ of $f$. It then follows immediately from the Laurent expansion of $f$ about $z_0$. It is rarely a good way to compute the residue, in my experience. The Laurent expansion is usually easier.

Comment: ... which means also, that the first (somewhat cryptic) sentence is not valid. I suggest that you reformulate the question given the comments you have so far.

Comment: Yes, I corrected it.

Comment: typo: d^{m-1} should be, instead of d^m

Answer (score 13):

I think it's more $$Res_{z_0}(f)=\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}(z-z_0)^mf(z)$$

To prove it, since $z_0$ is a pole of order $m$,
$$f(z)=\frac{c_{-m}}{(z-z_0)^m}+...+\frac{c_{-1}}{(z-z_0)}+c_0+...$$
and thus
$$(z-z_0)^mf(z)= c_{-m}+...+c_{-1}(z-z_0)^{m-1}+c_0(z-z_0)^m+...$$

Then, $$\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}(z-z_0)^mf(z)=(m-1)!c_{-1}+(z-z_0)(c_0+...).$$

Take the limit when $z\to z_0$ to conclude.