# Calculate the integral $\int_{\ |z| = 2} \frac{1}{(z^2 +1)^n} dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I want to calculate the integral $$\int_{\ |z| = 2} \frac{1}{(z^2 +1)^n} dz$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I thought about using the conclusion from Cauchy's formula which says: 
$$f^{(n)}(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int_{\ |z| = r} \frac{1}{(z-z_0)^n} dz$$

but here: 
$$\int_{\ |z| = 2} \frac{1}{(z^2 +1)^n} dz = \int_{\ |z| = 2} \frac{1}{(z-i)^n(z+i)^n} dz$$ and both $i$ and $-i$ are inside the circle $|z| < 2$ so I am not really sure what to do.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you know the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) yet?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't seen it yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That integral is equal to $0$, because it is equal to$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2ie^{it}}{\bigl((2e^{it})^2+1\bigr)^n}\,\mathrm dt.$$But\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2ie^{it}}{\bigl((2e^{it})^2+1\bigr)^n}\,\mathrm dt&=\int_0^\pi\frac{2ie^{it}}{\bigl((2e^{it})^2+1\bigr)^n}\,\mathrm dt+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}\frac{2ie^{it}}{\bigl((2e^{it})^2+1\bigr)^n}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^\pi\frac{2ie^{it}}{\bigl((2e^{it})^2+1\bigr)^n}\,\mathrm dt+\int_0^\pi\frac{2ie^{i(t+\pi)}}{\bigl((2e^{i(t+\pi)})^2+1\bigr)^n}\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_0^\pi\frac{2ie^{it}}{\bigl((2e^{it})^2+1\bigr)^n}\,\mathrm dt-\int_0^\pi\frac{2ie^{it}}{\bigl((2e^{it})^2+1\bigr)^n}\,\mathrm dt\\&=0.\end{align}

Comment: Yes, the answer had to be zero: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824918/sum-over-all-residues-is-zero

Comment: Nice answer, I had the feeling it would be 0. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You may apply residue theorem. To compute $\operatorname{res}_{z=i}\frac{1}{(z-i)^n(z+i)^n}$ you may express $\frac{1}{(z+i)^n}$ as a Taylor series around $i$ and find the $(n-1)$-th coefficient. Do the same for residue at $z=-i$
**Edit:**
So, $$\frac{1}{(z+i)^n}=\frac{1}{((z-i)+(2i))^n}=\frac{1}{(u+2i)^n}=f(u)$$
We want to find the coefficient of $u^{n-1}$ in the Taylor expansion around $u=0$. This is $f^{(n-1)}(0)/(n-1)!=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(-1)^{n-1}(n)(n+1)\dots(2n-1)(2i)^{-2n+1}$.

So,$\operatorname{res}_{z=i}\frac{1}{(z-i)^n(z+i)^n}= \frac{1}{(n-1)!}
(-1)^{n-1}(n)(n+1)\dots(2n-1)(2i)^{-2n+1}$

Similar approach proves $\operatorname{res}_{z=-i}\frac{1}{(z-i)^n(z+i)^n}= 
\frac{1}{(n-1)!}(-1)^{n-1}(n)(n+1)\dots(2n-1)(-2i)^{-2n+1}$

So when you add residues you get $0$.

Comment: Did you actually try to perform those computations?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use result on the residue of a function around a pole of order $n$?

Comment: @Jose Carlos Santos I don't have an explicit result (that's the job of the reader), but I know it will work.  Maybe I should add the hint to compute the $(n-1)$-th coefficient of $\frac{1}{(z+i)^n}$?

Comment: Is there a way without using the residue? I haven't learned it yet

Comment: @José Hdz. Stgo. Which result?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1480318/how-to-prove-the-formula-for-the-residue-of-f-at-a-pole-of-order-m

Comment: @José Hdz. Stgo. I see, I essentially proved that result in my edit.

Comment: @Gabi G I think you already got a an answer without residue theorem. But just to give you an idea of residue theorem: given a closed curve around $a$, we have $\int_\gamma (z-a)^m =0$ for all $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ except for $m=-1$ where you get $ \int_\gamma (z-a)^m =2\pi i$. So, that's why we only care about the $-1$ coefficient of the Laurent expansion (the residue).